# Card Description method improper use? Java

Tags: java, methods, substring

I am writing a program that takes user input to print a full description of a card. (i.e. 4S = Four of Spades)
After finishing the Card class, I tried using it to return the description of the card using a getDescription method, but it won't compile.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CardDescription {


public static void main(String[] args) {
Card c1 = new Card("KS");
System.out.println("Your card is" + c1.getDescription());
}}

public class Card {
private String value;
private String suite;
private String string1;
private String string2;

public Card(String s1){
value = s1.substring(0, 1);
suite = s1.substring(1);
}
public String getDescription(){
if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
    string1 = "Ace";
}
else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("K")){
    string1 = "King";
}
else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
    string1 = "Queen";
}
else if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("J")){
    string1 = "Jack";
}
else if(value.equals("10")){
    string1 = "Ten";
}
else if(value.equals("9")){
    string1 = "Nine";
}
else if(value.equals("8")){
    string1 = "Eight";
}
else if(value.equals("7")){
    string1 = "Seven";
}
else if(value.equals("6")){
    string1 = "Six";
}
else if(value.equals("5")){
    string1 = "Five";
}
else if(value.equals("4")){
    string1 = "Four";
}
else if(value.equals("3")){
    string1 = "Three";
}
else if(value.equals("2")){
    string1 = "Two";
}

if(suite.equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
    string2 = "Diamonds";
}
else if(suite.equalsIgnoreCase("H")){
    string2 = "Hearts";
}
else if(suite.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
    string2 = "Spades";
}
else if(suite.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
    string2 = "Clubs";
}

return string1 + " of " + string2;         
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Remove public keyword from "public class Card"

Comment: Also look at using `switch` statement instead of multiple else if.

Answer (score 0):

If both classes are in the same source file, they can't both be public. Either move Card class to Card.java or make it not public.

If the classes are not in the same file, they should either belong to the same package, or you should import the Card class in order to use it in the CardDescription class.

Other than that, your code works.

Comment: I actually did take it to Card.java, but it still won't work. The issue seems to be with this line
    Card c1 = new Card("KS");

Comment: @SamerBaslan What about `CardDescription` class? Is it in `CardDescription.java`?

Comment: @SamerBaslan I tried the code you posted, and it worked, so the only potential issue I can see is in the location of the classes.

Comment: Yes, it is in CardDescription.java
I also tried making them not public, wouldn't compile
The error is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class carddescription.CardDescription
 at carddescription.CardDescription.main(CardDescription.java:19)
Java Result: 1

Comment: @SamerBaslan Are both classes in the same package?

Comment: Lol, finally, it works. :)
They weren't in the same package.
Thanks a lot!